# What behaviour would you intuitively expect from the `deleted:no` search operator?

Tags: bug, search, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, 10k-tools

Appending **`deleted:no`** to a search query **does *not*** simply ***"exclude deleted posts"***, as one might expect (based on the "Advanced Search Tips" collapsible found on the the [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) page).

[image: advanced search tips]

Instead, it returns only ***"my"*** not-deleted questions (which I can see normally anyway).

[image: warning ss]  <sub><sup>*("...but I'm not searching **my** posts!")*</sup></sub>

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) provides a slightly better explanation, but those are *not* the search tips readily available from the [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) page.

---

Apparently **there is no way** to avoid inclusion of recently-deleted questions while searching for recent questions?

Obviously this only applies to users over 10k rep, when they are "granted" *[forced]* the "privilege" *[annoyance]* of seeing deleted posts, as part of the [moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) *[that I never wanted]*.

Comment: Agreed it's a problem, however I think you're misunderstanding how searching for deleted stuff works - you don't *need* to specify `deleted:no`. Seems like a meaningless operator - `deleted:yes` only searches your own posts - you can never search for somebody else's deleted posts. Also, if you *don't* add the `deleted` operator, you don't see deleted posts at all: The query `user:me` would give you all the non-deleted posts. Right now `deleted:no` seems to act as `user:me` but even were that to change, it needs to act as an empty filter and not do anything.

Comment: Example from me: [`created:2021-12-06..2021-12-08 user:3689450`](https://i.imgur.com/4FW7pd7.png) - returns one **non-deleted** post [`created:2021-12-06..2021-12-08 deleted:yes`](https://i.imgur.com/cPQNGKI.png) returns one **deleted** post. You don't see deleted posts without the operator. And you can only see your own deleted posts.

Comment: @VLAZ probably not meaningless for moderators though.

Comment: @RobertLongson in the context of this post, which describes how this particular user has employed it - it's meaningless. The operator *already* does different things depending on who uses it. It's not that much of a stretch to say that *for normal users* it's meaningless and can be changed, for moderators it can work in any other way. Again, it's not like it doesn't differentiate now. It's an empty operator for <10k users, it adds an automatic `user:me` for >=10k users.

Comment: The point isn't the use of the "deleted:no" - the point is that "deleted:[something]" is a valid operator. It's much the same as any of the others - you can use yes, no, 1 or 0 when using the operator - we don't list all of the options, just the fact that the operator exists and an example of what you can use to define it.